Survey-adjusted standard errors for a compound annual growth rate
I am trying to calculate a standard error for a compound annual growth rate.  Both the begin and final estimate are from a complex survey. I am using the following formula to calculate the growth rate:
cagr = (final / begin)^1/t - 1 
.0486 = (21342/16834)^(1/5)) - 1  

In my case, both final and begin have standard errors (168.1 & 228).  I am trying to figure out how to get a confidence interval around the .0486.  Both surveys are independent samples.

The delta method, automated
> inputs<-list(begin=16834,final=21342)
> formula <- quote((final / begin)^(1/5) - 1)
> derivative<- deriv(formula, c("begin","final"))
> varmat<-diag(c(228,168.1)^2)
> 
> cagr<-eval(derivative, inputs)
> dcagr<-attr(cagr,"gradient")
> var_cagr<- dcagr%*%varmat%*%t(dcagr)
> sqrt(var_cagr)
            [,1]
[1,] 0.003285846

This would also work if there were covariances -- you'd just define varmat appropriately.  If begin and final came from the same survey you could probably do this with survey::svycontrast.

thank you so much!
